# Troubleshooting a potentially faulty power supply

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I recently purchased a replacement power supply for my machine, and I am not able to get my machine to power on.  I am using:

ASUS A8R-MVP motherboard
hec Raptor500 500W ATX12V V2.2 SLI Ready Passive PFC Power Supply

The original power supply was this:
Antec TRUEPOWERII TPII-550 550W ATX12V SLI Certified CrossFire Ready Power Supply

When I plug the new power supply into the ATX 24pin and 4pin connectors and plug it into a power source, the motherboard power LED blinks and the machine will not power on.  This happens regardless of what peripherals are connected to the power supply.

Oddly enough, the machine does power on using a separate power supply, and this new power supply works fine in two other machines, one of which used an ATX 20pin connection, the other used a 24pin connection.

I'm wondering if I'm missing an installation step?  I cleared my CMOS RAM using the instructions in the motherboard manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the PC specs?

Maybe something in your MB is damage. Can be some of the connectors.
Try to work with other PSU on the current system, and see if it works.

If the system doesn't work with other PSU (not the HEC one) - the MB is probably the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have attempted to use other power supplies with this motherboard, and the machine boots and POSTs just fine.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you solved your problem :)
It will be nice if you'll choose my answer for the best answer, so that other users will use it in the future.

Comment: My problem remains unsolved.  As I mentioned in my original post, the hec power supply works fine on other machines that have tested, but not my machine.  My machine works fine with any power supply other than the hec one.  My question is, why does the hec power supply not work with my machine?

Comment: I'm apologize. I missed understood you.

What you're saying doesn't make any sense.
Well.. my last suggestion is to take the PSU (HEC) and replace him as long as the warranty exist.
If you can - I even recommend to carry your PC with you to the store, in order to show them a prof.

Comment: No worries, it was from Newegg, so I was considering returning it, just wanted to exhaust all of my options.  Thanks!  If you'll edit your answer, I'll accept it.